# How to get current language selected in android programmatically

Tags: android

This code i am  trying to get current language or default language of android phone

```
 String language = getApplicationContext().getResources().getConfiguration().locale.getLanguage();
```

but i am getting  always es which is english i have changes my phone language to Japanese language but then also i am getting es which is english. i am trying to apply language localisation so that on launch it will check device language accordingly it will set .

Please help me what i am doing wrong how to get current language selected of  android phone .

Comment: from what I remember application context will always return the first language that was selected on the app launch. You'd need to kill the app and restart it for application context to update its resources to a new locale

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are inbuilt functions which provide country and language data as follows

```
Locale.getDefault().getLanguage()        = en      
Locale.getDefault().getISO3Language()    = eng 
Locale.getDefault().getDisplayLanguage() = English
```

You can use this strings to check with your implemented locale to update app language.

Comment: Thanks for help this will return device language right ?

Comment: Yes it will return system language

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to write any code to localize your app's resources, if you structure your resources correctly the framework will do it for you. See [Using resources for localization](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization#using-framework) for a detailed description of how to achieve this.

Comment: thanks help me but when i will launch app then how i will detect device language so that i can set  as per device language ?

Comment: i have create folder for japana jpn in value folder you mean we should create  ja in resource folder then it will automatically pick language?

Comment: Correct, you don't need to write any code that would detect the language and pick the right set of resources - the system will do it for you. If you put your `strings.xml` with Japanese translations into `values-ja` the system will pick them up automatically if the device's primary locale is set to Japanese.

Answer (score 0):

Try This: (This might help others)

This will give you the selected language from app resource files.

```
getBaseContext().getResources().getConfiguration().locale;
getBaseContext().getResources().getConfiguration().locale.getLanguage();
getBaseContext().getResources().getConfiguration().locale.getDisplayLanguage();
```